# Using countifs() to compare two lists in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

So I'm using `Countifs()` because I have a few different criteria I want to check against a large dataset.

I want to take two series (e.g. `A2:A10` and `B2:B10`), and count how many times the A number is bigger than the corresponding B number (A2 vs B2, A3 vs B3, etc.) while also checking that a third series (`C2:C10`) is equal to a certain value.

Here's a rough version of what I've tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,">"&B2:B10, C2:C10,"1/1/2018")
```

So for this example, it would return 2:
[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Rdu.jpg)

I tried doing the Control+Shift+Enter for array formulas, but that didn't work.

EDIT: Thanks asher, you're right that formula does work with that example. But for some reason in this other example it doesn't: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvH5b.jpg) . It uses times instead of normal numbers, but that shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula, which only needs to be confirmed with ENTER...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A10>B2:B10),--(C2:C10="1/1/2018"+0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic works fine for me.  In Cell E1, I have this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A11,">"&B2:B11,C2:C11,"1/1/2018")
```

That yields 2.  Or, you could do the same with SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8>=B2:B8),--(C2:C8=E1))
```

Cell E1 contains '1/1/2018'

Comment: thanks! the SUMPRODUCT worked. the COUNTIFS worked for that example, but for some reason it doesn't work for another example I just added to OP

Comment: Please mark all answers as useful if they actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM() + IF() in an ARRAY Formula as follows:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A5>B2:B5,1,0)*IF(C2:C5=DATE(2018,1,1),1,0))
```

Confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER only as is an array formula so you get the brackets:

```
{=SUM(IF(A2:A5>B2:B5,1,0)*IF(C2:C5=DATE(2018,1,1),1,0))}
```